# deselect all rows in ng grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Please find the ng grid example in plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/CncDWCktXTuBQdDVfuVv?p=preview

It will allow user to select only one row but there will be one selected row at all time. I want to deselect all rows.

Comment: when you want to deselect?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana I have two tabs each containing a grid. The second grid is populated according to the selected value of first grid. If nothing is selected the second grid will populate all records.

Comment: If one row is selected from first grid. There should be an option to deselect that row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ng-grid has `keepLastSelected` option.

### Try:

`keepLastSelected: false` in gridOptions. This will toggle selection.

### Example

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData',
      selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
      multiSelect: false,
      keepLastSelected: false
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GVdaSmVR36Xmg9WGpyLY?p=preview)

First you need store gridApi:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
};
```

Then you can use:

```
$scope.unSelectAll = function(){
    $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply :

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows()
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Selecting ALL Rows We Use ::**

`$scope.GridOptions.api.selectAll()`

Here `$scope.GridOptions` is your own grid data

**And For Deselecting All Rows We use::**

`$scope.gridOptions.api.deselectAll();`

Here (.api) is file and you get this file from
(ag-grid.js) file from internet
Url:https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ag-grid